# Cargar archivos mientras se hace scroll en un Recycler View con retrofit

Tags: java, android, android-studio, retrofit

Soy nuevo en la comunidad y tengo un problema, quiero implementar el *Endless Scroll* o *Infinite Scroll* como algunos lo llaman en un `recycler view` para ir cargando elementos, ya que actualmente muestro los 11500 resultados en el `recycler view`, este mismo dentro de un `fragment`.

Se me olvido comentar que uso `Butterknife`.

Este es mi codigo en el `fragment`:

```
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private SolicitudesGeneradasAdapter adapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    private Call<SolicitudesGeneradasList> call;
    private SolicitudesGeneradasService service;

    private Unbinder unbinder;

    @BindView(R.id.swipeSolicitudesGeneradas)
    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeEventosRecientes;
    @BindView(R.id.tvResultados)
    TextView tvResultados;

    public SolicitudesGeneradasFragment() {}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_solicitudes_generadas, container, false);

        unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

        service = API.getApi().create(SolicitudesGeneradasService.class);

        call = service.obtenerSolicitudesGeneradas(API.KEY, getUUID());

        swipeEventosRecientes.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                refresh();
            }
        });

        call.enqueue(new Callback<SolicitudesGeneradasList>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<SolicitudesGeneradasList> call, Response<SolicitudesGeneradasList> response) {
                setSolicitudesGeneradas(response.body().getSolicitudes(), container, inflater);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<SolicitudesGeneradasList> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Al parecer algo salio mal", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    private void setSolicitudesGeneradas(final ArrayList<SolicitudesGeneradas> solicitudes, ViewGroup container, LayoutInflater inflater) {

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) container.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        adapter = new SolicitudesGeneradasAdapter(solicitudes, R.layout.recycler_view_manttos_correctivos, new SolicitudesGeneradasAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(String idSolicitud, int position) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetalleSolicitudActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("idSolicitud", idSolicitud);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(inflater.getContext());

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        tvResultados.setText(Integer.toString(solicitudes.size()) + " Resultados");

    }

    @OnClick(R.id.tvFiltros)
    public void filtros() {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Has pulsado los filtros!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void refresh() {
        getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .detach(SolicitudesGeneradasFragment.this)
                .attach(SolicitudesGeneradasFragment.this)
                .commit();
    }

    public String getUUID() {

        String uuid;

        uuid = Settings.Secure.getString(getActivity().getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);

        return uuid;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        unbinder.unbind();
    }

}
```

Este es el codigo de mi Adapter:

```
public class SolicitudesGeneradasAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SolicitudesGeneradasAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<SolicitudesGeneradas> solicitudesGeneradas;
    private int layout;
    public OnItemClickListener itemClickListener;

    public SolicitudesGeneradasAdapter(ArrayList<SolicitudesGeneradas> solicitudes, int layout, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        this.solicitudesGeneradas = solicitudes;
        this.layout = layout;
        this.itemClickListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public SolicitudesGeneradasAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(layout, parent, false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SolicitudesGeneradasAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        SolicitudesGeneradas solicitudesGeneradas = this.solicitudesGeneradas.get(position);

        holder.bind(solicitudesGeneradas.getIdSolicitud(),
                solicitudesGeneradas.getNombreSucursal(),
                solicitudesGeneradas.getFechaRegistro(),
                solicitudesGeneradas.getFolioSolicitud(),
                solicitudesGeneradas.getNivel(),
                solicitudesGeneradas.getSubcategoriaDescripcion(),
                solicitudesGeneradas.getUltimoStatus(),
                itemClickListener);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return solicitudesGeneradas.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        @BindView(R.id.tvNombreSucursal)
        TextView tvNombreSucurusal;
        @BindView(R.id.tvFechaHoraRegistro)
        TextView tvFechaHoraRegistro;
        @BindView(R.id.tvFolio)
        TextView tvFolio;
        @BindView(R.id.tvNivelEstatus)
        TextView tvNivelEstatus;
        @BindView(R.id.tvSubcategoriaDescripcion)
        TextView tvSubcategoriaDescripcion;
        @BindView(R.id.tvEstatus)
        TextView tvEstatus;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        }

        public void bind(final String id, final String sucursal, final String fechaRegistro, final String folio, final String nivel, final String subcategoriaDescripcion, final String ultimoEstatus, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
            tvNombreSucurusal.setText(sucursal);
            tvFechaHoraRegistro.setText(fechaRegistro);
            tvFolio.setText(folio);
            tvNivelEstatus.setText(nivel);
            tvSubcategoriaDescripcion.setText(subcategoriaDescripcion);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    listener.onItemClick(id, getAdapterPosition());
                }
            });
            tvEstatus.setText(ultimoEstatus);
        }
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(String name, int position);
    }
```

La verdad es que he seguido varios tutoriales, pero no me realiza la carga, no se si me estoy equivocando en algo o lo estoy aplicando mal, he pensado si es que tengo que poner un LIMIT en mi consulta de MySQL e irle pasando la cantidad que quiero ir agregando como si fuera la paginación de un sitio web.

Espero haberme explicado bien, de todos modos agradezco su atención.

Gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Hola que tal para Endless Scroll necesitas implementarlo de la siguiente manera :

El contador :

```
int page = 0
```

Dos Arreglos :

```
private ArrayList<History> listPage = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<History> listPageCopy = new ArrayList<>();
```

y usar el metodo del recyclerView que es addOnScrollListener con eso podremos saber cuando llega la final del scroll :

```
 listRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            if (!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1)) {
               page++
               //Haga puedes icorporar la logica que deseas
            }
        }
    });
```

El recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1) permite saber cuando se llega al final del recyclerView cuando pase eso llamas al servicio paginado para cargar al arreglo copia de la siguiente manera :

```
listPageCopy.add(x)
```

luego lo pasas al arreglo original de esta forma :

```
listPage.addAll(listPageCopy);
listPageCopy.clear();
```

Y al final borras el arreglo de copia para cuando vuelvas a llamar al servicio por el scroll del recyclerView solo baje la data nueva y no mantenga la anterior

-- Espero que de ayude esto